# does sp_delete_job also delete the associated job step?

Tags: sql-server, sql-job

does sp_delete_job also delete the associated job step?

Answer (score 2):

If you script out `sp_delete_job`, you will see near the end of the script: (Assumption is SQL Server)

```
DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules
WHERE job_id IN (SELECT job_id FROM #temp_jobs_to_delete)

DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobservers
WHERE job_id IN (SELECT job_id FROM #temp_jobs_to_delete)

DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps
WHERE job_id IN (SELECT job_id FROM #temp_jobs_to_delete)

DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
WHERE job_id IN (SELECT job_id FROM #temp_jobs_to_delete)
```